# how to convert char * to uchar16 in JNI C++

Tags: c++, character-encoding

here's what I am trying to do:

```
typedef uint16_t uchar16_t;
uchar16_t buf[32]; 
// buf will contain timezone information like GMT-6, Eastern Daylight Time, etc

char * str = "Test"; 

for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++)
     buf[i] = str[i];
```

I guess that's not correct since uchar16_t would contain 2 bytes and str contains 1 byte.

What is it that I am supposed to do ?

Comment: Also if you create a fixed length buffer like in that example, always make sure that you check the target buffer length in the loop as well or else KABOOM if you got a longer source string...

Comment: @humbagumba That fixed length buffer is part of an existing library. All I have to do is populate data into to that field. I don't have control over it's size or type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strlen? buf[32]? Trying to destroy the universe?

You want to use a wstringstream.

```
std::wstringstream lols;
lols << "Test";
std::wstring cakes;
lols >> cakes;
```

Edit@Comment:
You shouldn't use strlen because any decent string system allows embedded zeros, and strlen is seriously slow. In addition, you didn't resize your buffer as needed, so if you had a string of size > 31 you would get a buffer overflow. In addition, you would have to (if you did dynamically size your buffer) manually free it afterwards. Both of these things are serious failings of the C string system. My example code makes your standard library writer do all the work and avoid all these problems for you.

Comment: Well, I am learning - how will I learn unless you told me why is it wrong to do an strlen and what could be used in place of that? :)

Comment: @Sagar: For learning purposes, I suggest looking at this paper where Bjarne Stroustrup does a side-by-side analysis of "the C way" vs "the C++ way" of doing things (often the reason people think C is faster code is simply because you are omitting things that are required in order to be correct): http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/new_learning.pdf

Comment: @Hostile Fork: Thanks, that's really some valuable piece of information.

Answer (score 1):

That's actually OK if your string will always be ASCII. To do it correctly, the portable function is mbstowcs which assumes you're converting from the default locale or if you're on Windows then there's API functions that let you specify the source code page explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work, as long as `str` is ASCII; calling `strlen()` in the loop condition is probably a bad idea, though.  It might be easier to just use `swprintf()` if it's available on your system:

```
uchar16_t buf[32];
char *str = "Test";
swprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s", str);
```

Comment: Carl, what can I use in place of strlen instead - do I check for '\0'? My code does not work - when I print it, it prints all blank chars :(

Comment: @Sagar, What prints all blank chars?

Comment: after using swprintf, here's what I get:
Cannot convert from uchar16_t to wchar_t.

Answer (score 0):

[Have a look here](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/495008-8-bit-character-string-16-bit-character-string).

Also, is there a good reason you are defining your own type?

> If you have a (narrow) char string, you cannot convert it to
>   a wchar_t string by setting your locale to "C" and then passing
>   the string through mbstowcs(). That's because the "C" locale specifies
>   a -particular- character encoding, and that encoding might not match
>   the encoding of the execution character set, so mbstowcs() might
>   map the characters to something unexpected, or could even fail
>   (if the execution character set happened to use encodings that
>   were incompatible with the encoding structure for the C locale
>   character set.)
>
> Thus, in order to convert a char
>   string into a wider string, you have
>   to copy the chars one by one into an
>   array of wchar_t . If you need to work
>   with Unicode or utf-16 or whatever
>   after that, then wcstombs() is what
>   you should look at.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. The typedef has been done in an existing library so I have to use it 'as-is'.

Comment: wcstombs outputs a char* - I need a uint16_t So when I do that, it gives me an error saying "cannot convert from char* to uchar16_t*"